# Functional react native: when passing API data to render to the component gives an error: PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, fetch-api

> productData.js

```
const productsArray = [];

//api call being made to get all the products
async function getProductAPI() {
    try {
        let apiResultResponse = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
        let apiResultData = await apiResultResponse.json();
        return apiResultData;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
let dataa = getProductAPI();
dataa
    .then((data) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            productsArray.push(data[i]);
            console.log(productsArray);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

export default productsArray;
```

> Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Product from '../../components/Product';
import productsArray from '../../api/productData';

console.log(productsArray) //if this console.log is removed the value wont be rendered in the UI

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        productsArray.map((product, index) => {
            return (
                <Product product={product} key={index} navigation={navigation} />
            );
        })
    );
}
```

so the **error**: I get is

```
Array [
  Object {
    "category": "men clothing",
    "description": "Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in the forest. Stash your laptop (up to 15 inches) in the padded sleeve, your everyday",
    "id": 1,
    "image": "https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
    "price": 109.95,
    "title": "Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops",
  },
]
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    at read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
    at jsonParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:135:5)
    at call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at serveStatic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
    at call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:248:3)
```

My logic here was to make a separate file to hold different logic.
for instance I made that ***productData.js*** to consume an api and populate the array which will be exported to ***Home.js***.
when I do

```
console.log(productsArray)
```

It shows the output normally, and even renders on the simulator, but if I were to refresh my simulator I get that `PayloadTooLargeError`.

Is there some logic that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was add an ***custom hook*** logic.

should change the

> productData.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

//api call being made to get all the products
//making use of hook
let productsArray = () => {
    let [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(setData)
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, []);
    return data;
};

export default productsArray;
```

and need to make sure I call that hook inside the function component which is

> Home.js

```
import productsArray from '../../api/productData';



export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    let products = productsArray();  //important 
    return (
        products.map((product, index) => {
            return (
                <Product product={product} key={index} navigation={navigation} />
            );
        })
    );
}
```